# Dilemma with database organization - Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm creating a practice app which is essentially a Recipes database.

I'm trying to include a feature that allows users to search by ingredients, as many as they want.

Currently, my Recipe model has an ingredients column. And the ingredients is one long string. I am using Sequelize and by having all the ingredients in one long string, it allows me to query Recipes by multiple ingredients.

Consider the below. Please bear in mind, I only have 1 table (Recipes) currently.

```
**RecipesTable**

Recipe Name  | Ingredient (1 long string)
-----------------------------------------
RecipeOne    | "Tomato, Mushroom, Potato"
RecipeTwo    | "Brocolli, Lettuce, Potato"
RecipeThree  | "Tomato, Olives, Lettuce"
```

With my current setup, I can look query (easily with Sequelize) for Recipes that has Tomato, Potato - which will return RecipeOne. If I search for Tomato, Potato, Lemon, I will get nothing, because no strings contain those 3 words/ingredients.

I'm still new to databases and software engineering in general; but from what I've been reading... this breaks normalization (which I still need to understand its meaning).

Other threads on Stack Overflow advises to break Recipes and Ingredients into 2 separate tables, and create a relationship between them.

My question is this...

Should I break Recipes and Ingredients into 2 separate tables, but keep the ingredients as 1 long string.

```
**RecipesTable**

Recipe ID         |  Recipe Name
-----------------------------------------
1                 |  RecipeOne    
2                 |  RecipeTwo    
3                 |  RecipeThree  

**Ingredients**

Ingredients ID    |  Ingredients 
-----------------------------------------
1                 |  "Tomato, Mushroom, Potato"
2                 |  "Brocolli, Lettuce, Potato"
3                 |  "Tomato, Olives, Lettuce"

**RecipesIngredients**

Recipe ID         | Ingredient ID 
-----------------------------------------
1                 | 1
2                 | 2
3                 | 3
```

or should I break the ingredients into each row; which will make the Sequelize query much more difficult. I have attempted this and I'm not getting the results I'm looking for

```
**RecipesTable**

Recipe ID         |  Recipe Name
-----------------------------------------
1                 |  RecipeOne    
2                 |  RecipeTwo    
3                 |  RecipeThree  

**Ingredients**

Ingredients ID    |  Ingredients 
-----------------------------------------
1                 |  "Tomato"
2                 |  "Mushroom"    
3                 |  "Potato"
4                 |  "Broccolli"
5                 |  "Lettuce"
6                 |  "Potato"
7                 |  "Tomato"
8                 |  "Olives"
9                 |  "Lettuce"

**RecipesIngredients**

Recipe ID         | Ingredient ID 
-----------------------------------------
1                 | 1
1                 | 2
1                 | 3
2                 | 1
2                 | 2
1                 | 3
2                 | 3
3                 | 3
3                 | 3
```

If I break each ingredient into a record, and search for Tomato ingredient, I will get RecipeOne and RecipeThree. But if I add more ingredients to the query, I will get nothing because none of the strings contain multiple ingredients; as they're all single ingredient.

I can probably do something hacky, where I query one ingredient first, then `.filter` the rest. But ideally, I query via Sequelize only, rather than having to resort to a javascript array method...

With that said, apologies for the long post; but I'd appreciate any input on which option I should go with. I looked into Spoonacular API, and they seem to have their ingredients in one long string.

EDIT:

```
Ingredient.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: {
      name: {
        [Op.iLike]: array of ingredients
      }
    include: [Recipe]
    }
  } 
});

.then(results => {
  use .filter(results) or ES6 Set to remove the duplicates from the results      
})
```

Comment: Definitely last example is better. It's called database normalization. Give more info for your query that don't return results, when you search for two ingredients... What you want to show all recepies that have both ingredients or all recipies that have at least one of choosen igredients.

Comment: Ah... thank you.. have to rework everything then :'( I'd like to get recipes that have both/all queried ingredients, not or.

Comment: Read more about database normalization and joins.. then if you have questions about query you are welcome

Comment: hey, I haven't made any modifications yet or attempts. But I visualized the query to be something like in the above edit. Was wondering if I'm thinking in the right direction? I will of course make an attempt later today.

Comment: I gave you 2 duplicate questions: the first deals with storing delimited list of values in a field, the second shows you how to query a properly normalised ingridients table for two or more ingridients.